# Number parsing working in console but not in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here's my simple function, which is being called on the element as  `onclick="incrementValue(this)"`

```
function incrementValue(plusElement) {
  var choicesLeft = jQuery("#choicesLeft");

  choicesLeft.innerHTML = Number(choicesLeft.innerHTML) - 1;
  console.log(choicesLeft.innerHTML);
};
```

The `console.log` line prints out a **NaN** in the console.

However when I enter this line in the console:

`choicesLeft.innerHTML = Number(choicesLeft.innerHTML) - 1;`

The expected behavior occurs.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's `mealsLeft` ??

Comment: choicesLeft is a jQuery object and it does not have innerHTML. I highly doubt that would work in the console.

Comment: use `.text()` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: @epascarello is it still a jQuery object in the console?

Comment: If you are using $ in the console, it ain't jQuery, probably the alias for querySelector that chrome has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` will not work here since you call it on jQuery object.

Use `text()` instead of `innerHTML` :

```
choicesLeft.text( Number(choicesLeft.text()) - 1 );
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function incrementValue() {
  var choicesLeft = jQuery("#choicesLeft");

  choicesLeft.text( Number(choicesLeft.text()) + 1 );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick='incrementValue()'>Increment</button>
<br>
<span id='choicesLeft'>0</span>
```

Comment: text() suggestion was sufficient. Will accept you can stop editing lol. PS you injected a typo into `Hoep`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains several issues:

```
function incrementValue(plusElement) {
  var choicesLeft = jQuery("#choicesLeft");

  choicesLeft.innerHTML = Number(choicesLeft.innerHTML) - 1;
  console.log(mealsLeft.innerHTML);
};
```

First you use a parameter *plusElement* that is neve used.

Second you mix javascript with jquery.

*choicesLeft*, is a jquery object and you should use the jquery api to interact with.

So you should have something:

```
var choicesLeftNum = Number(choichesLeft.text());
```

or

```
var choicesLeftNum = +choichesLeft.text();
```

or
    var choicesLeftNum = parseInt(choichesLeft.text(), 10);

Than you could decrement:

```
choichesLeft.text(choicesLeftNum - 1);
```

You should use *text()* instead of *html()* as you don't want html content if any. You're ok with the whole text.